# In React, why is my array thought to be empty in a function triggered by a websocket message?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, websocket, closures

In React I have an array variable defined using `useState`, called `messages`. I also have a component on the page which doesn't have any DOM but rather listens for events on a websocket. When my component gets advised of an event from the websocket, the length of my `messages` variable is always zero - despite it having multiple messages previously. How come the array is empty at the time the function is entered?

Here's a minimal set of code which reproduces the issue:

`WebSocketNotificationHandler.tsx`:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import config from "../../../config.json";
import { IChatMessage } from "../../../services/chatService";

interface WebSocketNotificationHandlerProps {
  onReceiveMessages: (newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => void;
}

export let client: WebSocket = new WebSocket(
  config.webSocketAddress,
  config.webSocketProtocol
);

const WebSocketNotificationHandler = (
  props: WebSocketNotificationHandlerProps
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (client) {
      client.onmessage = async (ev) => {
        handleWebSocketMessage(ev);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const handleWebSocketMessage = async (ev: MessageEvent<string>) => {
    props.onReceiveMessages([]); // Simplified, normally we send one or more
  }

  return (
    <></>
  );
}

export default WebSocketNotificationHandler;
```

And `GroupPage.tsx`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import chatService, { IChatMessage, ICreateMessageResponse } from '../../../services/chatService';
import ChatMessage from '../../atoms/ChatMessage/ChatMessage';
import ChatStagingArea from '../../organisms/ChatStagingArea/ChatStagingArea';
import WebSocketNotificationHandler from '../../organisms/WebSocketNotificationHandler/WebSocketNotificationHandler';

const GroupPage = () => {
  const { groupName } = useParams();

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<IChatMessage[]>([]);

  const loadGroup = async () => {
    setMessages([]);
    await chatService // REST API to get current messages, returns a list >0 elements
      .getGroup(groupName)
      .then(data => {
        setMessages([...data.data.messages]);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadGroup();
  }, []);

  const handleMessageSent = (message: ICreateMessageResponse, text: string) => {
    let newMessages = [...messages, { /* Message data for a new message */ }];
    setMessages(newMessages);
  }

  const handleNewMessages = (newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => {
    console.log(messages.length); // Always 0 even if I can see multiple???
    // Code goes here that adds the newMessages to the messages array
  };

  return (
    <>
      {messages && messages.map(m => <ChatMessage key={m.id} author={m.fullName} date={m.authoredDate} message={m.message} />)}

      <ChatStagingArea groupName={groupName} onSent={(message, text) => handleMessageSent(message, text)} />

      <WebSocketNotificationHandler onReceiveMessages={newMessages => handleNewMessages(newMessages)} />
    </>
  );
}

export default GroupPage;
```

Comment: For your simplified version your will always get 0 leanth as you are hard coding an empty array. Also, why do you need to make that function async?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue is that of a stale closure over the `messages` state in the `handleNewMessages` callback that is called in the anonymous function passed to `WebSocketNotificationHandler` as `onReceiveMessages` where it's called by `handleWebSocketMessage` that actually instantiates the `client.onmessage` event handler.

The initially empty `messages` state array is what is closed over in scope from the initial render cycle when the event handlers and callbacks are instantiated.

## Solution

If you are simply just wanting to append the sent messages and to append the array of received messages then your handlers in `GroupPage` should really be using functional state updates. Functional state updates pass a callback function to the state updater function that is passed the current state value and you compute and return the next state value. This avoids the issue of stale closures over state values you are trying to update from.

Example:

```js
const handleMessageSent = (message: ICreateMessageResponse, text: string) => {
  setMessages(messages => [...messages, { /* Message data for a new message */ }]);
  
  // or setMessages(messages => messages.concat({ /* Message data for a new message */ }));
};

const handleNewMessages = (newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => {
  setMessages(messages => [...messages, ...newMessages]);

  // or setMessages(messages => messages.concat(...newMessages));
};
```

If you want to console log the `messages` state array length then use a separate `useEffect` hook for this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(messages.length);
}, [messages]);
```

If you ***really*** must log the `messages` state array length in the `handleNewMessages` then use a React ref to cache the current `messages` state value so the ref's current value can be accessed at any time during the component lifecycle.

Example:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<IChatMessage[]>([]);

const messagesRef = useRef<IChatMessage[]>(messages);

useEffect(() => {
  messagesRef.current = messages;
}, [messages]);

...

const handleNewMessages = (newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => {
  console.log(messagesRef.current.length);

  setMessages(messages => messages.concat(...newMessages));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, when the `handleWebSocketMessage` function is executed, it points to the initial state of messages which is an empty array even if the state has changed in the parent `GroupPage` component.

You can use the `useCallback` hook to create a memoized version of the `handleNewMessages` function, this will ensure that the function always refers to the latest version of the `setMessages` function.

```
const WebSocketNotificationHandler = (props: WebSocketNotificationHandlerProps) => {

    const handleWebSocketMessage = useCallback(async (ev: MessageEvent<string>) => {
        props.onReceiveMessages([]); // Simplified, normally we send one or more
    }, [props.onReceiveMessages]);

};
```

same applies to the `grouppage` component as well..

```
const GroupPage = () => {
    const handleNewMessages = useCallback((newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => {
        console.log(messages.length);
        // Code goes here that adds the newMessages to the messages array
    }, [messages]);
};
```

Answer (score -3):

WebSocketNotificationHandler.tsx:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import config from "../../../config.json";
import { IChatMessage } from "../../../services/chatService";

interface WebSocketNotificationHandlerProps {
  onReceiveMessages: (newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => void;
}

export let client: WebSocket = new WebSocket(
  config.webSocketAddress,
  config.webSocketProtocol
);

const WebSocketNotificationHandler = (
  props: WebSocketNotificationHandlerProps
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWebSocketMessage = async (ev: MessageEvent<string>) => {
      props.onReceiveMessages([]); // Simplified, normally we send one or more
    };

    if (client) {
      client.addEventListener("message", handleWebSocketMessage);
    }

    return () => {
      client.removeEventListener("message", handleWebSocketMessage);
    };
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};

export default WebSocketNotificationHandler;
```

GroupPage.tsx:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import chatService, { IChatMessage, ICreateMessageResponse } from '../../../services/chatService';
import ChatMessage from '../../atoms/ChatMessage/ChatMessage';
import ChatStagingArea from '../../organisms/ChatStagingArea/ChatStagingArea';
import WebSocketNotificationHandler from '../../organisms/WebSocketNotificationHandler/WebSocketNotificationHandler';

const GroupPage = () => {
  const { groupName } = useParams();
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<IChatMessage[]>([]);

  const loadGroup = async () => {
    setMessages([]);
    await chatService.getGroup(groupName).then(data => {
      setMessages([...data.data.messages]);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadGroup();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNewMessages = (newMessages: IChatMessage[]) => {
      setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, ...newMessages]);
    };

    return () => {
      WebSocketNotificationHandler.client.removeEventListener("message", handleNewMessages);
    };
  }, [messages]);

  const handleMessageSent = (message: ICreateMessageResponse, text: string) => {
    let newMessages = [...messages, { /* Message data for a new message */ }];
    setMessages(newMessages);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {messages && messages.map(m => <ChatMessage key={m.id} author={m.fullName} date={m.authoredDate} message={m.message} />)}
      <ChatStagingArea groupName={groupName} onSent={(message, text) => handleMessageSent(message, text)} />
      <WebSocketNotificationHandler onReceiveMessages={newMessages => handleNewMessages(newMessages)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default GroupPage;
```

These changes ensure that the WebSocket events are properly handled, and the messages state is updated correctly when new messages arrive. The cleanup of WebSocket listeners is also taken care of to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: 10 answers, some of them lengthy, with an average interval of less than 11 minutes looks like the typical [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) workflow. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785242/can-we-control-js-with-the-help-of-css-properties-is-that-possible/76785504#76785504) had the slip-up *"my last update in September 2021"*.